# How should grounding be handled for multiple RV pad feeds?

Tags: electrical, grounding

Trailer pads were wired at my deer camp over 15 years ago.  The main power pole has meter with 200 amp disconnect.  From the meter a 3 wire service was run overhead to each pad.  At the first breaker box it is grounded with ground rod.  All the other breaker boxes just have the 3 wire service to them.  All breaker boxes past the first one only have 1 ground neutral bar in them.  The ground and neutral wires are all bonded to this single bar. I need add a new breaker box so I can add an RV 50 amp 4 wire plug in.

Should I separate the ground neutral wires in the new box and do I need to put in a ground rod?

Answer (score 2):

NEC 551.76.C (RV and RV parks) Grounded conductor not to be used as equipment ground. 
To me that says you need to isolate the ground and neutral and will need a rod at your site.

Comment: Yes, the NEC has been eliminating three wire feeds for the last several cycles. Your sub panel should be fed with four wires and the ground and neutral should remain separated.

Answer (score -2):

if you are using the existing feeder u might be able to add to it. around here they will grandfather it in.  but if it's new or in different location and not tied into old one you definitely have to run 4 wire to it/no ground rod required at outlet. but if it's to a panel on a pole, then yes, ground rod or two depending. ask your AHJ

Comment: Can you cite any code that is different than than the one I cited? This is a new or different than the 15 year old park. 50 amp RV outlets are 240v , not 30 amp 120v as the op suggests since a neutral and a ground. 2017 code jumped the requirement for 50 amp outlets no mention of that, when a larger service is needed an update is needed even though the op did not come back I will take the - because you have not cited code or a code legal proposal.

Comment: Hello, again. You've been away for three years, and then posted four somewhat slapdash answers in the last hour. You should spend a little more time thinking about your answers before you post them; it'll be much appreciated by all.